# MutationObserver - is callback executed before re-rendering the page?

Tags: javascript, performance, mutation-observers

I was wondering if when observing elements (and/or its children; subtree: true and childList: true), the browser waits with applying changes (rendering them) until my callback has finished?

Because I need my callback to do changes to the DOM that fast, that the initially observed mutations (in parts) dont take effect.

Thanks if somebody knows.